# How to inherit background-color into an SVG fill?

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to adapt SVG file image as an inline element with dynamic control of the colors.

The code below is React, but I don't think that matters to the question.  There's no CSS processing in our pipeline (SCSS, Sass, etc).

The icon I'm working with has two components, a filled outer circle and some letters inside that circle.

As explained in the comment - I'm trying to not change the source SVG too much.

I want the "circle" to inherit the foreground color of its context, which I do by defaulting the `fill` color to `currentColor`, and I want the "letters" to inherit the background color by default.

At the moment, I just default the letter color to a value that works in most contexts and then customise in other places (for example, using the icon on a button where we've changed the colors and "white" doesn't make sense for the letters).

```tsx
/*
https://orcid.figshare.com/articles/figure/ORCID_iD_icon_graphics/5008697
https://orcid.figshare.com/articles/figure/ORCID_iD_icon_graphics/5008697?file=8439059
ORCIDiD_iconBwVector.svg
 */
export function OrcidSvgIcon({circleColor, letterColor}: {
  circleColor?: string, letterColor?: string
}){
  // currentColor is some kind of SVG keyword for "color"
  circleColor = circleColor ?? "currentColor";
  // can't figure out what "background" equivalent of currentColor is
  letterColor = letterColor ?? "white";

  /* Pretty sure we want to get rid of the text/css style and do normal fill,
  but trying to keep SVG content as close as possible to the source for now. */
  
  return <SvgIcon viewBox={"0 0 256 256"} x={0} y={0}
    xmlSpace={"preserve"}
  >
    <style type="text/css">{`
      .st0{fill:${circleColor};}
      .st1{fill:${letterColor};}
    `}</style>
    <path className="st0"
      d="M256,128c0,70.7-57.3,128-128,128C57.3,256,0,198.7,0,128C0,57.3,57.3,0,128,0C198.7,0,256,57.3,256,128z"/>
    <g>
      <path className="st1" d="M86.3,186.2H70.9V79.1h15.4v48.4V186.2z"/>
      <path className="st1" d="M108.9,79.1h41.6c39.6,0,57,28.3,57,53.6c0,27.5-21.5,53.6-56.8,53.6h-41.8V79.1z M124.3,172.4h24.5
      c34.9,0,42.9-26.5,42.9-39.7c0-21.5-13.7-39.7-43.7-39.7h-23.7V172.4z"/>
      <path className="st1" d="M88.7,56.8c0,5.5-4.5,10.1-10.1,10.1c-5.6,0-10.1-4.6-10.1-10.1c0-5.6,4.5-10.1,10.1-10.1
      C84.2,46.7,88.7,51.3,88.7,56.8z"/>
    </g>
  </SvgIcon>
}
```

Is there a way to specify a specific `fill` should use the *background* color from the parent context?

Comment: Why not use CSS *custom variables*? This way you can style/theme your colors in CSS independently from `currentColor` and `background-color`. Something like `circleColor = circleColor ?? "var(--circleFill)"; letterColor = letterColor ?? "var(--letterFill)";`...

Comment: @RenevanderLende AFAIK custom variables are global, not context sensitive, I want the two colors to cascade down from the FG and BG colors of the containing component to be used as circle and letter colors in the icon.  Exactly as I'm doing with `currentColor`, but I want to source from the `background-color` as well.

Comment: Not sure if I read you correctly, but *custom variables* are only visible within the scope they have been defined, which is not necessarily `:root`. Siblings and parent will be unaware. So the scope is the context. As `var(..)` fallback value you could use `unset` or a default color.

Comment: @RenevanderLende So you're saying to define the SvgIcon to use embedded CSS variable names, then set those variables manually to the desired colors in the context where I am using the component?  How would that be materially different from just passing the colors in via the properties I've already defined on the component level?  Passing via props, or setting via CSS variables - either way still requires me to customise the colors myself?

Comment: With an absent `currentBackground` you will have to get the default value from somewhere. For all I know some JS config object providing `currentThemeDefaultColors.buttonBackgroundColor`  would make much more sense. Crux is to be independent from hardcoded values. Custom vars in a stylesheet seems an easy way out, for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `fill-opacity: 0;`?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/fill-opacity